# how to always load any url/link of a domain in reader view in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, reading

I visit [wuxiaworld.com](http://wuxiaworld.com) & spend a lot of time reading pages on the site in **Reader View** in **Firefox**

I have subscribed to RSS feed of the website & when I click on it, the page opens in Firefox, & I have to manually enter Reader View each time.

Is there a way to load any url / link from a particular domain in Reader View automatically? (such as an extension or script)